# pkgin installation problem (NetBSD)

Tags: software-installation, package-management, bsd, netbsd

I just installed [NetBSD 7.1.1 (**i386**)](https://www.netbsd.org/releases/) on my old laptop.

During the installation, I could not install pgkin (I don't know why), so I skipped it and now I have a NetBSD 7.1.1 installed on my laptop without pkgin.

My problem is "**How to install pkgin on NetBSD (i386) ?**"

I found [this Unixmen tutorial](https://www.unixmen.com/howto-install-pkgin-on-netbsd-6/) and I followed it:

I tried :

```
#export PKG_PATH="http://ftp.netbsd.org/pub/pkgsrc/packages/NetBSD/amd64/6.0_BETA_current/All/"
# pkg_add -v pkgin
```

And I got :

```
pkg_add: Can't process ftp://ftp.netbsd.org:80/pub/pkgsrc/packages/NetBSD/amd64/6.0_BETA_current/All/%0d/pkgin*: Not Found
pkg_add: no pkg found for 'pkgin',sorry.
pkg_add: 1 package addition failed
```

I know this is a wrong command because this ftp address is for amd64 while my laptop and this NetBSD is i386. (I can't find the correct command for i386 )

I also followed instructions of [pkgin.net](http://pkgin.net/), and I did

```
git clone https://github.com/NetBSDfr/pkgin.git
```

on another computer and copied the output (which is a folder name pkgin) to my NetBSD (my NetBSD doesn't have 'git' command)

and then I did :

```
./configure --prefix=/usr/pkg --with-libraries=/usr/pkg/lib --with-includes=/usr/pkg/include
```

and then :

```
make
```

but I got :

```
#   compile  pkgin/summary.o
gcc -O2    -std=gnu99    -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -Wmissing-prototypes -Wpointer-arith -Wno-sign-compare  -Wno-traditional  -Wa,--fatal-warnings -Wreturn-type -Wswitch -Wshadow -Werror    -DPKGIN_VERSION=\""0.9.4 for NetBSD-7.1.1 i386"\" -DNETBSD  -g -DLOCALBASE=\"/usr/local\"           -DPKG_SYSCONFDIR=\"/usr/local/etc\"         -DPKG_DBDIR="\"/var/db/pkg\""           -DDEF_LOG_DIR="\"/var/db/pkg\""         -DPKGIN_DB=\"/var/db/pkgin\"            -DPKGTOOLS=\"/usr/local/sbin\" -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE -D_LARGE_FILES -DCHECK_MACHINE_ARCH=\"i386\" -Iexternal -I. -I/usr/local/include  -c    summary.c
*** Error code 1

Stop.
make: stopped in /root/pkgin
```

I think this error occurs because of the dependencies. (which is mentioned in [pkgin.net](http://pkgin.net/)) but still, don't know how to install those dependencies.

EDIT:
I found "http://ftp.netbsd.org/pub/pkgsrc/packages/NetBSD/i386/7.1.1/All/"
but it still says

```
no pkg fond for 'pkgin', sorry
```

**SOLVED:**

** I solved the problem by writing 7.1 instead of 7.1.1**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you should use http://ftp.netbsd.org/pub/pkgsrc/packages/NetBSD/i386/7.1/ - because you installed i386 and version 7.1.

So:

```
export PKG_PATH=http://ftp.netbsd.org/pub/pkgsrc/packages/NetBSD/i386/7.1/
pkg_add -v pkgin
```